# Syntax error in exec statement?

Tags: php, exec

I tried the following two lines within php:

```
echo exec('tail -n +5 $newname2.ppm | tr -d "\r \n" | tr -d "55" > $newname2.ppm1');
echo exec('sed "s/2/1/g" $newname2.ppm1 > $newname2.ppm2');
```

However nothing happens.

How can I rewrite these two lines, either that it works as execution, or within php directly?

Comment: What syntax error do you facing. write here

Comment: I don't know, it just does not do what it would do on the command line. No errors, no log.

Comment: If I replace $newname2.ppm $newname2.ppm1 and $newname2.ppm2 with /var/www/BB/images/backgrounds/news0000.ppm /var/www/BB/images/backgrounds/news0000.ppm1 /var/www/BB/images/backgrounds/news0000.ppm2  then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, ... there are special characters in it, like " \r \n

I changed it to:

```
$cmd_1 = "tail -n +4 " . $newname2ppm . " | tr -d \"\\r \\n\" | tr -d \"55\" > " . $newname2ppm1;
echo "<br />cmd_1 = " . $cmd_1;
$cmd_2 = "sed \"s/2/1/g\" " . $newname2ppm1 . " > " . $newname2ppm2;
echo "<br />cmd_2 = " . $cmd_2;

echo exec($cmd_1);
echo exec($cmd_2);
```

Now it works!